# How to auto-populate mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error while running my code,

> INSERT INTO `widgets` (`id`, `page`, `location`, `title`, `content`,
>   `global`) VALUES right(1, '/', '', 'Welcome to Animal Rights
>   Pakistan', '
>
> Animal Rights Pakistan is a collaboratively edited
>   **question** and **answer** site built to
>   suit your needs.
>
> \r\n\r\n
>
> It''s easy to use, with no registration
>   required!
>
> \r\n\r\n
>
> co/questions/ask">ask a question
>
> ', 1);

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right(1, '/', '', 'Welcome to Animal Rights Pakistan', '<p>Animal Rights Pakista' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the query without 'right'~

Comment: `VALUES right` should be `VALUES`

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the 'right' after values:

```
INSERT INTO widgets (id, page, location, title, content, global) 
VALUES(1, '/', '', 'Welcome to Animal Rights Pakistan', 
'Animal Rights Pakistan is a collaboratively edited question and answer site built to suit your needs.\r\n\r\n. It''s easy to use, with no registration required!', 1);
```

And for the link you better add another filed to the table called as 'reference' and echo it inside an "a href='' .." element!